# How to add dynamically stretching gap between widgets in Qt?

Tags: qt, pyside6

I want to add spaces between the widgets, dynamically, so that, as i resize the window, the widgets get their gaps adjusted accordingly, so that the widgets will be evenly spread over the available window space.

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import random

try:
    from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        for i in range(0, 10):
            self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello World",
                            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter,
                            styleSheet   = f'''
                                background-color: '#999999';
                                color           : '#000000';
                            '''
                        )
            self.layout.addWidget(self.text)

        self.layout.addStretch()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.resize(800, 600)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set labels' vertical size policy to `QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum` or `QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed` and remove `self.layout.addStretch()` you'll get evenly spread stretch.

```py
self.text.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
```

Alternatively you can add `self.layout.addStretch()` after every label to achieve same thing.